# Shared counter concurrent incrementation using atomic integer

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, race-condition, atomicinteger

Hi I am new to multithreading. Was trying to understand the concept of Atomic integer. I have a shared counter variable which is incremented by two threads

```
class MyCounterClass{
    volatile AtomicInteger sharedCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public int incrementCounter() {
        for(int i = 0; i <10000; i++){
            // add 1
            sharedCounter.incrementAndGet();
        }

        return this.sharedCounter.get();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyCounterClass myCounterClassObj = new MyCounterClass();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " +myCounterClassObj.incrementCounter());
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " " + myCounterClassObj.incrementCounter());
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}
```

I thought my output from 2 threads will be 20000. But I am getting 20000 as output of one thread and other one shows some random value between 10000 and 20000.
Could anyone help me understand what is happening here

[image]

Comment: It's not showing "a random value" - it's showing "a value between 10,000 and 20,000 inclusive". Why would you expect the output to be 20,000, twice? That would only happen if *both* threads reached `return this.sharedCounter.get()` after *both* threads have completed all 10,000 increments. One thread is very likely to finish a bit before the other one - at which point the counter won't be 20,000.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good catch - I've been staring at that code for a few minutes and didn't see that until your comment popped up - and yet it looks so obvious in hindsight.  And I've been writing multithreaded code for decades.  I think a lot of people don't realize just how hard multithreaded programming can be.  Human brains really just don't work that way.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for your reply. You are right. My expected output was wrong! did  not realise untill i saw your comment!!

Comment: Will convert my comment into an answer in that case...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not showing "a random value" - it's showing "a value between 10,000 and 20,000 inclusive". It has to be at least 10,000 because the thread that's printing has incremented the counter 10,000 times, and it has to be at most 10,000 because the *other* thread will have incremented the counter *at most* 10,000 times.

It would only show 20,000 twice if both threads reached return `this.sharedCounter.get()` after *both* threads have completed all 10,000 increments. One thread is very likely to finish a bit before the other one - at which point the counter won't be 20,000.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I thought my output from 2 threads will be 20000. But I am getting 20000 as output of one thread and other one shows some random value between 10000 and 20000. ..."*

This is because the last invocation of *incrementCounter* by *thread 1* had incremented *sharedCounter* to *19923*.
The following *77* iterations would have been completed by *thread 0*.

Here is an example.

```java
static class Count {
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();

    int increment() {
        return i.incrementAndGet();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Count count = new Count();
    Thread a
        = new Thread(() -> {
            int i;
            do System.out.println("a " + (i = count.increment()));
            while (i < 10);
        });
    Thread b
        = new Thread(() -> {
            int i;
            do System.out.println("b " + (i = count.increment()));
            while (i < 10);
        });
    a.start();
    b.start();
}
```

Here are a some outputs.

Output

```
a 1
b 2
b 4
b 5
b 6
b 7
b 8
b 9
b 10
a 3
a 11
```

```
b 2
a 1
b 3
a 4
b 5
b 7
a 6
b 8
b 10
a 9
a 11
```